# How to draw shapes using the grouping thing

Tags: python, pygame

I just learned how to group stuff in pygame but when I try to use it to draw a sprite it says: " ExternalError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined on line 32"

Here is my code:

```
import pygame 
from pygame import *

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Block():
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, typ):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
        self.w = w 
        self.h = h 
        self.typ = typ
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
        self.accX = 0 
        self.accY = 0
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, 20, 20))
player = Player(0, 0)

while True:
    Blocks = Block(0, 0, 100, 50, 1)
    blocks.add(Blocks)
    blocks.draw(screen)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

---

This means `Block` and `Player` must to be derived from `pygame.sprite.Sprite` and has to have the attributes `rect` and `image`. Add the `Block` and `Player` instances to a `Group` and us the `darw()` method to draw them.

Complete example:

```py
import pygame 
from pygame import *

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, typ):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill((127, 127, 127))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
       
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
objects = pygame.sprite.Group()

block = Block(0, 0, 100, 50, 1)
blocks.add(block)

player = Player(0, 0)
objects.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:   
    clock.tick(60) 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    blocks.draw(screen)
    objects.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```